# Binding a ComboBox DataTemplate inside a DataGrid in an AvaloniaUI/ReactiveUI app

Tags: wpf, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am building an MVVM app with AvaloniaUI/ReactiveUI and EF Core to be able to edit a few tables with data.
I guess the fact that I use AvaloniaUI does not play too much of a role though.
If I had used WPF the problem would probably be the same (seems more to be a ReactiveUI issue).

As an example assume two tables, Classes and Instructors, where Classes holds a foreign key to the Instructors table.

Classes and Instructors have the following models:

```
class Class
{
    //Primary key
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Foreign key to Instructors table
    public int InstructorID { get; set; }
    //Navigation property
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}

class Instructor
{
    //Primary key
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The main view model contains collections both of these as

```
public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
public List<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
```

I want the classes to be displayed in a DataGrid. For that I used
programmatic (type-safe) ReactiveUI bindings like so

```
<DataGrid Name="DGClasses">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instructor"
                        Binding="{Binding Instructor.Name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


...
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Classes, x => x.DGClasses.Items); 
this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.SelectedClass, x => x.DGClasses.SelectedItem);
...
```

So far this works well, the Instructor column even displays the name
of the instructor although the Classes table contains only the foreign key
into the Instructors table (this works by means of the navigation property
in the Class class).

For editing the Instructor of a class the column should use a ComboBox
as editor so I can select from all existing Instructors. I started with

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Instructor">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ComboBox Items="{Binding ??? }">
      </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But this is where I'm stuck. A direct binding expression does not work
because the Instructors collection is not a subproperty of Class and
I know of no way to programmatically bind the Items property (ItemsSource
in WPF) in a DataTemplate in a DataGrid column. Since I use the programmatic
ReactiveUI binding with all (top-level) elements I also don't have set
the DataContext property of the Window that contains the DataGrid.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your combobox item collection to some special attached property on the `DataGrid` (or just use `Tag`) and do something like `{Binding $parent[DataGrid].Tag}`.